# How do i move to a new Activity after onChildClick has been clicked in an ExpandableListView without ExpandableListView appending to the new Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

**To clarify**, I was able to move from the Fragment `class` to the new Activity `class/view`.  However, the problem is the `ExpandableListView` is appending to the new Activity and I can't figure out how to get rid of that when I move to the new activity.

This is my code:

**CategoriesFragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/categoriesID">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expand_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listGroup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_group"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**listItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CategoriesFragment class**

[categoriesFragment before a child is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml7yW.png)

[image of new activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YT25.png)

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private ArrayList<Group> listDataHeader;
    private ArrayList<Group> originalList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//in order to create optionalMenu method


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expand_view);

        initData();

        this.originalList = new ArrayList<Group>();
        this.originalList.addAll(listDataHeader);

        listAdapter = new CategoriesViewModel(getActivity(), listDataHeader);

        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String currentGroupName = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getGroupName();

                Intent groupChatIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), GroupChatActivity.class);
                groupChatIntent.putExtra("groupName", currentGroupName);

                startActivity(groupChatIntent);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    }

new Activity that is been called


public class GroupChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ImageButton sendMsgButton;
    private EditText userText;
    private ScrollView scrollMsgView;
    private TextView displayText;
    private String currentGroupName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_chat);

        currentGroupName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("groupName").toString();

        initializeField();

    }

    private void initializeField() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(currentGroupName);

        sendMsgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send_msg_button);
        userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_group_msg);
        displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.group_chat_text);
        scrollMsgView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    }
}
```